# Is -Args a correct substitute for -ArgumentList?

Tags: powershell

I came across some code using `Start-Process` in this form.

```
Start-Process <cmd> -Args <arguments>
```

On checking the [Start-Process docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1), it says `Start-Process` takes a parameter of `-ArgumentList` but doesn't actually mention `-Args`.

Is this shortening documented somewhere or is it just a known thing that you can shorten `ArgumentList` to `Args`? If so, do they behave in the same way?

Comment: Same thing just shortened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's already documented on the same link.`Args` is an alias name for `ArgumentList`.

> -ArgumentList
>
> Specifies parameters or parameter values to use when this cmdlet starts the process. Arguments can be accepted as a single
> string with the arguments separated by spaces, or as an array of
> strings separated by commas. The cmdlet joins the array into a single
> string with each element of the array separated by a single space.
>
> The outer quotes of the PowerShell strings are not included when the
> ArgumentList values are passed to the new process. If parameters or
> parameter values contain a space or quotes, they need to be surrounded
> with escaped double quotes. For more information, see
> about_Quoting_Rules.
>
> Type: String[]
>
> ***Aliases:   Args***
>
> Position: 1
>
> Default value:    None
>
> Accept pipeline input:    False
>
> Accept wildcard characters:   False

Comment: Oh man I totally missed that ‍♂️‍♂️ Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`-Args` is an Alias for `-ArgumentList` as mentioned on [Abdul Niyas P M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68249993/15339544) answer, parameters in PowerShell can have many aliases. This can be particularly useful for example on **functions that accept value from pipeline by property name**.

- See [Benefits of Using Aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/parameter-aliases?view=powershell-7.1#benefits-of-using-aliases)

```
function SayHello {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [alias('alias1','alias2')]
        [string]$Message
    )

    "Hello $Message"
}
```

```
PS /> [pscustomobject]@{ Message = 'World!' } | SayHello
Hello World!

PS /> [pscustomobject]@{ alias1 = 'World!' } | SayHello
Hello World!

PS /> [pscustomobject]@{ alias2 = 'World!' } | SayHello
Hello World!
```

If you want to know if a functions has aliases you can always use `Get-Help`:

```
PS /> Get-Help Start-Process -Parameter * |
Where-Object Aliases -NE 'none' |
Select-Object Name, Aliases

name                   aliases
----                   -------
ArgumentList           Args   
Credential             RunAs  
FilePath               PSPath 
LoadUserProfile        Lup    
NoNewWindow            nnw    
RedirectStandardError  RSE    
RedirectStandardInput  RSI    
RedirectStandardOutput RSO
```

---

Other relevant documention:

- [about_Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=A%20pipeline%20is%20a%20series,sent%20to%20yet%20another%20command.)
- [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1)
- [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Very useful, thank you! `Get-Help Start-Process -Parameter ArgumentList | Select-Object Name, Aliases` gives me the answer very quickly

Comment: No problem, happy to help @pjpscriv